# WebAPI 2.0 call monitoring

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

Using ASP.NET WebAPI 2.0 and have a conceptual issue.

Would like to keep a global record of any API that is called by any user/ client and it would be awesome if this was stored in the database.

What would be the best mechanism to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I' using a `DelegatingHandler` for a long time in several projects which is doing just fine.

```
public class ApiCallLogHandler : DelegatingHandler {
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

        var started = DateTime.UtcNow;
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        Exception baseException = null;

        try {
            response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        } catch(Exception exception) {
            CommonLogger.Logger.LogError(exception);
            baseException = exception;
        }

        try {
            var callModel = await GetCallModelAsync(request, response);
            if(baseException != null)
                callModel.Exception = baseException
            callModel.ExecutionTime = (DateTime.UtcNow - started).ToString();
            await CommonLogger.Logger.LogApiCallAsync(callModel);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            CommonLogger.Logger.LogError(exception);
        }

        return response;
    }

    private async Task<ApiCallModel> GetCallModelAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response) {
        // parse request and response and create a model to store in database...
    }
}
```

By this approach you are able to track all requests, exceptions during execution, and even full-response of each API call.

`ApiCallModel` is just a simple POCO class which you should fill it with your required data from request and response.

`CommonLogger.Logger.*` is your logging mechanism.

And, you have to register the handler with this snippet:

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ApiCallLogHandler());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is great, how would I be able to save data in database?

Comment: @user1144596 I don't get it ): do it in `CommonLogget.Logger.*` or just a custom method. you can use EF or NH or ASO.NET or any other mechanisms you want. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @user1144596 you're welcome. by the way, it's weird that you accept the answer but didn't vote it up ;) :)))